# android:: how to add suitable delay during playing a video in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am a newbei to android. Currently, I am playing a video from a URL in android VideoView.
I have search a lot in order to find out a way, how to add repetitive delay in video playing via android code.

With Thread.sleep(3000), i can delay it only 1 time But i want to delay the video playing after every 5 seconds.

Task:
Condition 1: For User 1
I have to add repetitive delay during the playing of the video; means the video will play for 5 seconds and then it will encounter a delay of approx. 4-5 seconds. In fact, i am trying to create a situation which will show the observer that there is some delay during video buffering.

Any solution.

Thanks

private void playVideo() {

```
    try {
    final String path = "http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp";
        if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(CStreaming.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 

        else {              
            **Thread.sleep(3000);**
            // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
            Log.v(TAG,"Thread Sleep ....3000 msec");
            if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            current = path;
            Log.i(TAG,"Value of path in PlayVideo()=" + path);
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));

            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            }
```

}

// getDataSource method which will be used by playVideo()

```
private String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException {
    if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
        return path;
    } else {

        URL url = new URL(path);
        URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat",this.getCacheDir());
        temp.deleteOnExit();
        String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
        do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);
        Log.i(TAG,"Buffer Printing via Array: " + Arrays.toString(buf));
            if (numread <= 0)
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        } while (true);
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return tempPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //--code run in Main, UI thread  
        DoSomeThing();
    }
};

h.postDelayed(r,2000); //-- run after 2 seconds
```